# Submit button not working when selecting item from particular select box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a select box. when select one option another select box is displayed, and when select other option a text box is displayed.

First i selected the first option of the first select box and the text box appears. when i submit it works fine.

But when i select the second option a select box appears with data using jquery and the item of second select box is selected and submitted. but sumbit button is not getting triggered.

[This is this jquery code using which i am getting the select data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4WjZ.png)

[this is the div inside which i append select tag with data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlhEP.png)

I am getting the data to the select box. but while submitting after selecting this particular select options sumission not happening.

Can anyone please help

Comment: Please provide some code because right now we cant really help you

Comment: Now that we have a nice description of the code, can we see the code?